# how to get details of the pl sql package after parsing in java

Tags: java, parsing, plsql, antlr

I have a pkb file. It contain a package and under that package it has multiple functions.

I have to get the following details out of it:

1. package name
2. function names (for all functions one by one)
3. params in function
4. return type of function

**Approach:** I am parsing the pkb file. I have taken the grammar from these sources:

1. [Presto](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-parser/src/main/antlr4/com/facebook/presto/sql/parser/SqlBase.g4)
2. [Antlrv4 Grammer for plsql](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/plsql/plsql.g4)

After getting these grammar I downloaded the jar from [antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar](http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar). Then using

```
java -cp org.antlr.v4.Tool grammar.g
```

one by one I execute this command on these grammars separately to generate listener, lexer, parser and other files.

After this I created two project in eclipse one for each grammar. I imported these generated file into the respective and set `antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar` file into the path. After this I used following code to check if my .pkb file is correct or not?

```
public static void parse(String file) {
    try {
        SqlBaseLexer lex = new SqlBaseLexer(new org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream(file));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
        SqlBaseParser parser = new SqlBaseParser(tokens);

        System.err.println(parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors()+" Errors");


    } catch (RecognitionException e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    } catch (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError e) {
        System.err.println(file + ":");
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    } catch (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.err.println(file + ":");
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }       
}
```

I am not getting any error in parsing the file. 
But after this I am stuck with next steps. I need to get all the package name, functions, params etc.

**How to get these details?**

**Also is my approach is correct to attain the required output.**

Comment: Do you have to include private subprograms? If you only need the public ones it might be easier to just query `all_arguments`.

Comment: Well I need both public and private. And how to get public ones? Which way you are stating?

Answer (score 1):

The Presto grammar is a generic SQL grammar which is not suitable for parsing Oracle packages. The ANTLRv4 grammar for PL/SQL is the right tool for your task.

Generally an ANTLR grammar as such works as a validator. When you want to make some additional processing while parsing you should use ANTLR actions (see overview slide [in this presentation](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/NFJS/ANTLR3.pdf)). These are blocks of text written in the target language (e.g. Java) and enclosed in curly braces (see [documentation](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/actions.md#actions-and-attributes)).

There are at least two ways to solve your task with ANTLR actions.

### Stdout output

The simplest way is to add `println()`s for certain rules.

To print package name modify `package_body` rule in `plsql.g4` as follows:

```
package_body
    : BODY package_name (IS | AS) package_obj_body* 
      (BEGIN seq_of_statements | END package_name?) 
      {System.out.println("Package name is "+$package_name.text);} 
    ;
```

Similarly to print information about function's arguments and return type: add `prinln()`s in `create_function_body` rule. But there is an issue whith printing of parameters. If you use `$parameter.text` it will return name, type specification and default value  according to `parameter` rule without spaces (as token sequence). If you add `println()` to `parameter` rule and use `$parameter_name.text` it will print all parameter's names (including parameters of procedures, not only functions). So you can add an ANTLR return value for `parameter` rule and assign `$parameter_name.text` to the return value:

```
parameter returns [String p_name] 
: parameter_name (IN | OUT | INOUT | NOCOPY)* 
  type_spec? default_value_part?
  {$p_name=$parameter_name.text;}
;
```

Thus is context of `create_function_body` we can access the parameter's name by `$parameter.p_name`:

```
create_function_body
: (CREATE (OR REPLACE)?)? FUNCTION function_name 
  {System.out.println("Parameters of function "+$function_name.text+":");}
  ('(' parameter {System.out.println($parameter.p_name);} 
  (',' parameter {System.out.println($parameter.p_name);})* ')')?  
  RETURN type_spec 
  (invoker_rights_clause|parallel_enable_clause|result_cache_clause|DETERMINISTIC)*
  ((PIPELINED? (IS | AS) (DECLARE? declare_spec* body | call_spec))
   | (PIPELINED | AGGREGATE) USING implementation_type_name) ';'
  {System.out.println("Return type of function "
                      +$function_name.text+" is "
                      + $type_spec.text);}
;
```

### Accumulation

Also you can save some calculations to variables and access them as parser class members. E.g. you can accumulate function's name in variable `func_name`. For this add `@members` section at beginning of the grammar:

```
grammar plsql;

@members{
  String func_name = "";
}
```

And modify `function_name` rule as follows:

```
function_name
  : id ('.' id_expression)? {func_name = func_name+$id.text + " ";}
  ;
```

### Using lexer and parser classes

Here is an example of application to run your parser `parse.java`:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class parse {
   static String readFile(String path) throws IOException 
   {
       byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
       return new String(encoded, "UTF-8");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       // create input stream `in`
       ANTLRInputStream in = new ANTLRInputStream( readFile(args[0]) );
       // create lexer `lex` with `in` at input
       plsqlLexer lex = new plsqlLexer(in);
       // create token stream `tokens` with `lex` at input
       CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
       // create parser with `tokens` at input
       plsqlParser parser = new plsqlParser(tokens);
       // call start rule of parser
       parser.sql_script();
       // print func_name
       System.out.println("Function names: "+parser.func_name);
   }
}
```

### Compile and run

After this generate java code by ANTLR:

```
java org.antlr.v4.Tool plsql.g4
```

and compile your Java code:

```
javac plsqlLexer.java plsqlParser.java plsqlListener.java parse.java
```

then run it for some `.pkb` file:

```
java parse green_tools.pkb
```

You can find modified `parse.java`, `plsql.g4` and `green_tools.pkb` [here](https://gist.github.com/lana-k/3c8326a1eda5b51e1c338cc6022db200).